# Autofac's IsRegistered Returns True For Not Registered Components

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, autofac

I'm using this base ViewController to apply property injection for all Xamarin iOS ViewController using a single service locator instead of the common way of resolving the dependencies using a static container in each of the ViewControllers, however, the IsRegistered method returns true for the ChildViewControllers array which was of course not something that I would register in an Autofac container, moreover it throws an exception when it tries to resolve it

that's how I register the container:

```
public static IContainer Container { get; set; }  
public static void Register()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    RegisterDataService(builder);
    Container = builder.Build();
}
private static void RegisterDataService(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Register(c => new ToDoDataServices(new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformIOS(), path)));
}
```

and that's how I resolve

```
public class ExtendedViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ExtendedViewController(IntPtr ptr) : base(ptr)
    {
        RegisterDependency();
    }


    private void RegisterDependency()
    {
        var type = GetType();
        var props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var propType = prop.PropertyType;
            var isRegistered = RegisterComponents.Container.IsRegistered(propType);
            if(!isRegistered)
                continue;

            prop.SetValue(this, RegisterComponents.Container.Resolve(propType));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question: the exact type or types that you think aren't registered but say they are; and the code you're using to set up your container.

Comment: (Really need the exact type that's failing. `IEnumerable<Xamarin.IController>`? `MyProject.MyViewController[]`?)

Comment: Also, have you tried just doing `RegsiterComponents.Container.InjectProperties(this)` rather than a bunch of custom logic?